# How can I check if a field has a validation in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `Address` model that contains the following validation:

```
with_options if: Proc.new{|i| i.country && i.country.downcase == "united states"} do
    validates :state, presence: true
end
```

In my new and edit form, I want to check and see if the state field is required. The following function returns the presence validation but it does not take my conditional into consideration.

```
Address.new._validators[:first_name]
```

This code returns

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00007fadebc9d8a8 @attributes=[:first_name], @options={:if=>#<Proc:0x00007fadebc9ebb8@/Users/cannonmoyer/Documents/RailsProjects/treadmilldoctorrails/app/models/address.rb:18>}>]
```

Is there a way to run the conditional for the validation so that the presence validator doesn't appear on each instance? I am wanting to use this to set required fields within my HTML.

Comment: This is conceptually flawed - `_validators` returns a list of the validations (which are basically callbacks) that will be run when the validation callback is fired or you call `#valid?` on the model. The `if/unless` options are evaluated when the validations are run just like the corresponding option for callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just place the condition into a method on its own then you can use the same method in your view to determine if you want to show the states select.

```
validates :state, presence: true, if: :state_required?

def state_required?
  country && country.downcase == "united states"
end
```

And in your view you can do something like:

```
<% if @address.state_required? %>
  # state select
<% end %>
```